# Open "Add reminder..." dialog for mail item in Outlook using VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook

Using Outlook 2013 32-bit under Win10 64-bit.

In VBA, suppose I have a mailitem object. I know I can set the various task/reminder options individually through my own form if I want to create one. It seems like it would be a lot easier if I could cause Outlook's "Add reminder ..." dialog to display for the mail item, but I haven't found any references to it.

This is the dialog as it appears in the Outlook:
[image: Add Reminders dialog]

(As an aside, I can get the Categories dialog to come up using myMailItem.ShowCategoriesDialog, but there doesn't seem to be anything similar for reminders.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the Add Reminder dialog box button on the ribbon, depending on what window is active it will act and will tie the reminder object (and/or follow up object etc) to a mail item.

If you have no mail item open it will tie it to the mail items that are selected in the inbox (one or more), By default only one item is selected, which is highlighted with a gray or light blue background. You can hold the CTRL key down and select more mail items and then click the Add Reminder to apply the reminder to all of those items.

If a mail item is already open and active then the reminder will be applied only to that mail item. For your case that it seems you want to apply the reminders one by one we will go with the latter method. Find the mail item we want and then open it, and then open the Add Reminder dialog box, and when you hit ok, it will save it and close the active window. This code finds the most recent mail item, but you should be able to change the selection criteria:

```
Private Sub PopUpReminderDialogBox()
    Dim iLatest As Long
    Dim myFolder As Object
    Dim myNameSpace As Object
    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application

    Set olApp = Outlook.Application 'you can initiate a New application too
    Set myNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    iLatest = myFolder.Items.Count
    Set myItem = myFolder.Items(iLatest)

    myItem.Display 'to make the mailitem currentitem
    olApp.ActiveInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("AddReminder")
    myItem.Close olSave
End Sub
```

If you wanted by any chance to open up the reminder dialog box when one or more mail item is highlighted in the inbox, then you need to use

```
    olApp.ActiveExplorer.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("AddReminder")
```

instead of

```
    olApp.ActiveInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("AddReminder")
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to set a reminder on a message already in the Inbox. In either case, your proposal does not address my question, which is whether it is possible using VBA to get Outlook to display the "Add Reminder ..." dialog from the UI as illustrated above. Thanks!

Comment: I added an example that sets up a follow-up for an item in the inbox. I am not sure why you want to display the follow up window at the same time, it does not make sense, the whole purpose of using VBA is avoiding dealing with the UI tools

Comment: The objective is to interact with the user to set the dates. As I noted, I can build my own form to ask for the dates, but it seemed like it would be easier to use the Outlook dialog, the same way I use the Outlook Categories dialog. [Really, though, I think my question is completely clear. I don't need help working around this, but thanks for offering. I just wanted to know if there was a way to invoke the Outlook Add Reminder dialog.]

Comment: definitely, there is, I will look some more to see if I can figure it out

Comment: One question: what criteria do you have to pick the mail item from the inbox and then display the reminder dialog box?

Comment: Let's say I loop through the mail folder (Inbox or Sent) and display the reminder dialog for every message that has no reminder (ReminderSet=False).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @ibo. That was very helpful, so I have accepted it as the answer.

Here is a mock-up of a macro that simulates what I wanted to do. The fact that it changes the explorer that is visible in the Outlook UI whenever the code points to a different folder was useful in my case, but in the general case it would be better to have a method that didn't use the UI at all. I just don't think there is one.

<========================== EDITED =========================>

I found out by experimentation that changing the folder in the active explorer actually takes a lot of time (from the CPU perspective), so in many cases the explorer is not ready to clear the selection and select the chosen item unless you force the macro to wait. Usually a second or two is enough. I modified the code to allow up to 10 seconds.

I also learned that the EntryID, as the unique identifier of a folder, is a good alternative to using the Is operator, which does not work whenever two objects were not "Set" equal to each other.

```
Public Sub testMSO()

'This test macro selects the last item in the Inbox, but it could be
' any item in any available folder.

Dim loItem As Object
Dim loNewFold As Folder
Dim loOldFold As Folder
Dim loExplorer As Explorer
Dim lbFoldChg As Boolean
Dim liLoops As Integer
Dim ldWait As Date

On Error Resume Next 'Mimimal error handling, just for demonstration purposes

'Get the Inbox folder.
Set loNewFold = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

'Get the active explorer.
Set loExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer

'The current and "new" folders always compare as different using the Is operator
' because Is determines whether two objects were Set equal, so just use the
' unique EntryID to determine if they are really different.
If loExplorer.CurrentFolder.EntryID = loNewFold.EntryID Then
    lbFoldChg = False
Else
    lbFoldChg = True

    'Save the explorer's current folder
    Set loOldFold = loExplorer.CurrentFolder

    'Assign the Inbox to the active explorer. Note that this is preferable to the
    ' loNewFold.Display method, which is disconcerting to the user because it opens
    ' a new explorer (new Outlook window).
    Set loExplorer.CurrentFolder = loNewFold

End If

'Arbitrarily pick the last Inbox item.
Set loItem = loNewFold.Items(loNewFold.Items.Count)

'Make the chosen item the only selected item.
If lbFoldChg Then

    'Selection takes place in the Outlook UI, so if the folder changes, it takes
    ' quite a while in CPU terms to load the explorer and get it ready to change
    ' the selection, so wait up to 10 seconds in 1-second increments.

    For liLoops = 1 To 10
        If loExplorer.IsItemSelectableInView(loItem) Then
            loExplorer.ClearSelection
            loExplorer.AddToSelection loItem
            Exit For
        Else
            ldWait = Now + (1 / 86400)  'Add a second to current date/time
            Do While Now < ldWait
                DoEvents
            Loop
        End If
    Next liLoops

    If liLoops = 11 Then
        MsgBox "Unable to select mail item in folder " & loItem.Parent.Name, _
                vbOKOnly + vbExclamation
        GoTo cleanup
    End If

Else

    'If the folder has not changed, no need to wait.
    loExplorer.ClearSelection
    loExplorer.AddToSelection loItem

End If

'Display the Add Reminder dialog if it is available. It might not be available
' if the item is, for example, an meeting item, or if the chosen folder does
' not support reminders.
If loExplorer.CommandBars.GetEnabledMso("AddReminder") Then
    loExplorer.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "AddReminder"
End If

cleanup:

If lbFoldChg Then
    'Point the explorer back to the original folder.
    Set loExplorer.CurrentFolder = loOldFold
End If

'Clean up
Set loExplorer = Nothing
Set loNewFold = Nothing
Set loOldFold = Nothing
Set loItem = Nothing

End Sub 'testMSO
```

Comment: I don't think either that there is a straightforward way of activating that dialog box, it is controlled by the OS and not the VBA. Those commands are just implementation of windows functions in VBA. The bad part is that one cannot make an item active using VBA so I thought the best way is to open the item to make it active.

Comment: That makes sense. I wasn't thinking of them as part of Windows. It also helps me as I'm trying to understand [this TechNet article](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Scroll-as-New-Messages-are-190668a3) that gets an Outlook explorer to scroll to the top. It uses a lot of Windows API calls. So maybe there is a way after all....

Comment: All of such solutions are simulating manual entries with the UI and it is not really a good way of doing things in the background. I use such approaches if I have no choice really. One reason is that they act differently from one UI or another, from one OS to another and if the user is still playing with mouse or keyboard, the code does sth wrong

Comment: @Ibo - I agree that the use of the UI is a poor approach, especially across operating systems. I made a couple of unrelated discoveries and modified my answer above to account for them.