# Open “Add reminder” dialog for mail item by Close event

Tags: vba, events, outlook, dialog

I would like to get the dialog box for a follow-up flag and CategoriesDialog box to set a reminder when I close the mailitem.
I tried to modify the code from [here](https://ideasmiths.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/solution-to-create-vba-codes-for-outlook-inspector-close-event-handler/). When I close a mailitem, all things remain normal and I get the category dialog. I can not get the dialog box for follow-up flag like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782511/open-add-reminder-dialog-for-mail-item-in-outlook-using-vba). There is no error message popup.

```
Public WithEvents objInspector As Outlook.Inspector
Public WithEvents colInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Init_colInspectorsEvent
End Sub

Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    Init_colInspectorsEvent
End Sub

Private Sub Init_colInspectorsEvent()
    'Initialize the inspectors events handler
    Set colInspectors = Outlook.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub colInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal NewInspector As Inspector)
    If NewInspector.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then MsgBox "New mail inspector is opened"
    If NewInspector.CurrentItem.Class = olTask Then MsgBox "New Task inspector is opened"
    If NewInspector.CurrentItem.Class = olContact Then MsgBox "New Contact inspector is opened"
    Set objInspector = NewInspector
End Sub

Private Sub objInspector_Close()
If objInspector.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then 'MsgBox "Mail inspector is closing"
    objInspector.CurrentItem.ShowCategoriesDialog
    objInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("AddReminder") 'No error but not work
    objInspector.CurrentItem.Save
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need to display a dialog window right after the inspector window is closed?

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev That’s an intelligent question. since I would like to force myself to consider the mail item priority in my working flow. I have a habit that I would like to open a mail when it comes to my inbox, but I don't necessarily have time to deal with it immediately, so I need to give myself a reminder or follow up flag for an incoming mail, if need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method for displaying the `Add Reminder...` dialog.

The best what you can do is to execute a built-in control programmatically:

```
CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("AddReminder")
```

But I don't think the `Close` event handler is the right place for such things.

Comment: After searching a few information, I also find MS don't provide Add Reminder dialog like `ShowCategoriesDialog` . furthermore, if you mean that I cant not use the script of  `CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("AddReminder")` in close event?

Comment: The `Close` event handler is not the right place for calling UI built-in buttons/controls. We can't be sure they are still alive. So, that is why it works sometimes, and sometimes not. Nobody can guarantee that an inspector UI is still accessible and not destroyed.